# xAPI / Tin Can to LRS to LMS

Tags: scorm, tin-can-api, xapi

I am trying to better understand how xAPI / Tin Can works (I'm going to call it xAPI henceforth)

Previously I was developing for a SCORM 1.2 LMS where there were 'records' such as: **Raw Attempts**, **Status** and **Raw Score** for each content package. The LMS wants to upgrade to xAPI but I am unsure about the theory behind how xAPI works.

On http://tincanapi.com/learning-record-store/ it states that:

> The data stored in an LRS can be accessed by LMSs, reporting tools, or other LRSs, and can be stored as individual learning records and/or entire transcripts

Subsequently on http://www.learningsolutionsmag.com/articles/1271/the-xapi-and-the-lms-what-does-the-future-hold it also states that:

> An LMS that has a built-in LRS supports the Experience API and also does all the other things LMS products do to manage learning delivery.

The question is,

What exactly does this relationship between an LMS and LRS entail? I need the ability to set the said LMS 'records' from an application that resides **outside** the LMS, how do you do this using xAPI?

Or maybe I've completely misunderstood the xAPI LRS and it is designed to completely replace LMS records?

Thanks for the help. Links to informative resources on this will also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ADL released a few resources about xAPI and SCORM see...  
http://adlnet.github.io/SCORM-to-TLA-Roadmap/   and...  
http://adlnet.github.io/xAPI-SCORM-Profile/

Comment: A very nice hybrid between the two is cmi5 in case anyone is still trying to make this transition. Here is a link comparing the three: https://www.learningsolutionsmag.com/articles/1697/experience-api-cmi5-and-future-scorm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A LRS is a Learner Record Store which is a series of statements about what the learner did or is doing.  Someone can correct me, but I believe Activity Streams were created by Social Media entities around 2006, and different entities adopted/extended it for a flavor of e-learning standards.

If we deconstruct the two real quick (high level) -

An LMS was a portal with assignments, reports, maintenence/admin tools, forums etc ... sometimes a LCMS (learning content management system) and other variations of an all-in-one web based solution.
AICC was developed during CBT (DOS - Disk Operating System), then browsers (pre-XML). SCORM came shortly after (post XML, pre JSON) around 2001 now living in the world of Browsers (HTML/CSS/JS, Macromedia/Adobe Flash, and others).
So with SCORM you are essentially bundling up little portable websites, which later we were able to extend to use content media servers, or CDNs to keep the 'logic' and 'assets' externalized. SCORM was based upon sharing training via a CAM/PIF package, which included a manifest/table of contents, and your HTML files, which covered the packaging portion of the specification.  The second part of this was the Runtime. The LMS will expose this runtime to manage the student attempt. This, in a way, is like the 'statements' only that it is the entire student attempt data or CMI object. This includes: scoring, Interactions, Objectives, and other data points.  SCORM 2004 Extended this further to make much of the specification manditory, forcing the LMS to support richer Sequence and Navigation capabilities.  These were often deemed too complicated, and hard to manage mainly due to a lack of tools and support.  But people do use them.

A LRS via an 'endpoint' is much like you posting statements to a server. There are XML and JSON implementations of this.  So in away, when you deploy your 'app' you're passing in a URL for it to communicate with.
You can actually convert some of the SCORM centric stuff into an xAPI statement, but keep in mind xAPI doesn't control packaging, or sequence and navigation.  All of this is now based on your Application (web, iOS, Android, etc ...) managing this.  It mainly allows a non-HTML application to now take advantage of training, since SCORM was primarily a JavaScript communication standard.

So you have to take a pro/con look at what you're trying to do, how SCORM or xAPI, Activity Streams or some proprietary approach fits your needs.

A xAPI statement may look something like :

```
{
actor: {
    name: "Learner Name",
    objectType: "Agent",
    account: {
        homePage: window.location.href,
        name: "Learner ID"
    }
},
verb: {
    id: "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/completed",
    display: {
        "en-US": "completed"
    }
},
object: {
    id: "commonly a URI",
    objectType: "Activity",
    "definition": {
        type: "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson",
        "name": {
            "en-US": "Some Name"
        },
        "description": {
            "en-US": "Some Description"
        }
    }
},
result: {
    completion: true,
    success: true,
    duration: 'PTHMS'
    score: {
        scaled: 0.9        
    }
}
```

}

SCORM, is mainly locating the LMS Runtime (API_1484_11 or API) and then making method calls to Initialize, Set/Get Value, Commit and Terminate.
CMI Object (for SCORM 2004) looks a bit more like this once its filled in.
https://gist.github.com/cybercussion/4675334

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the in-depth reply and history of the two systems! So once I have sent a statement (such as the one above) to the LRS, how can I then transfer the result.completion value to the corresponding completion field in the LMS? The github link seems to suggest that I just send the data via SCORM 2004, I just wanted to confirm this? and also, does tincan mean that I can send SCORM 2004 data from applications outside of the LMS? Thanks and really appreciate all the help!

Comment: LRS is really a seperate mechanism for recording status.  So the LMS could read records stored there to maintain status.  SCORM is really seperate from xAPI too.  But, you can migrate your SCORM communication to post statements to a LRS endpoint.  It won't happen automatically, unless things have been configured to do so.  This page may help that scenario a bit - http://scorm.com/tincanoverview/what-is-an-lrs-learning-record-store/

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. That's what I thought you were unfortunately going to say haha. Cheers!

Comment: There are more things popping up as time goes on.  I've already had to do a little of this 'conversion' style work.  SCORM 1.2 doesn't use the time duration required by xAPI, so that takes an extra step to convert it, but it's absolutely feesible long as you have access to either the content or the LMS Runtime API.  Student also typically needs to be authenticated with the endpoint, or else they have to login.  SCORM was just searching for a variable name on the webpage to communicate with.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I am going to have to find out exactly what I can get access to on the LMS side of things as I'm unsure at the moment... Where are you putting these 'conversions'? On / In the LRS, LMS or content?

Comment: I've implemented it on a LMS, and you can use it like a shim (interceptor) for cases where you don't have access to the Runtime or have the time to decouple it from the backend or JavaScript (popular problem).  Many of the examples online are commonly watered down so statements about Interactions vs. finishing with results all depends if you take an open source copy of a LRS endpoint or use SCORM Cloud or another endpoint.  But again in the case of an external endpoint the student would need to authenticate with it as well.  Something like Degreed.com where they can track activity.

Answer (score 7):

#### What I have learned

It is *best practice* to use the LMS for content delivery and the LRS for analytics. All reporting goes through the LRS which will track **extended data**, then the LMS will track its **normal data** (scorm1.2 etc) .

Let the LMS do what it does now - course completion, bookmarking and serving the content to the user. Then use LRS for more complex data capture - which path, how long on an interaction, answer given, selection of answers chosen - your *"who did what how"*.

'Most people' using xAPI have ditched their LMS and everything is now done via the LRS i.e. They have dropped hybrid LMS/LRS structures - Why? Because this uncouples all possible learning mediums - apps, videos, face to face etc can now all be tracked in one system to form a more cohesive architecture for analysis / auditing / reporting.

When deploying an iPad app, this directly communicates with the LRS and at no point in time is the LRS able to communicate with the LMS unless YOU write some custom 'web hooks' / code to tie the 2 together - not consensually recomended.

When deploying browser based learning, you can jointly send data to both the LMS and LRS seperately - drawing from the LRS when we need additional analytics about what the learner has done and then leaving the LMS to retain its current functionality - "are we done yet".

---

#### Summary

To answer my original question. There is no default relationship between the LMS and LRS. If the content is outside the LMS - it is OUTSIDE the LMS permanently - it does not interact with it in anyway. Consider just mimicking the same data fields of the LMS into your LRS calls and run custom reports from the LRS's database.

---

#### Notes

Thanks to @Mark for his detailed explanation on the 2 systems and assisting my inital understanding of the systems.

This information has been gained from work related experiences - sorry no official sources.

Comment: anytime.  This subject is definitely laced with the dependency on reporting or lack there-of. I similarly struggled with the concept of "who wants to authenticate with some random endpoint and post academics?".  Similarly to managing google analytics, and beefing up what your users are accessing there are the fact you actually need to know who the student is, how their interaction aligns to content or an objective and that can be very scary as you may not want your academics posted 'elsewhere'.  I've even seen e-learning companies use google analytics for this type of info too!

Comment: well detailed answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand the question, but will try to answer anyway.

There's a few different ways an LRS might relate on an LMS. I've listed these in order of how common they are amongst LMS vendors today and the order that many LMS vendors seem to be following.

1. The LMS might launch learning experiences. When doing so, it might provide the learning experience with some security credentials and an endpoint url for an LRS so that the learning experience can track back to the LRS. These learning experiences might be packaged content uploaded to the LMS or external content.
2. The LMS might include an LRS as part of the LMS application.  See, for example [here](http://tincanapi.com/lrs-lms/lrs-for-lmss-home/?utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=lrs-for-lmss?pmc=em-1). LRSs included within an LMS should always have the functionality to connect to an external LRS.
3. The LMS might pull data from the LRS, for example to use in dashboards and reports or to support completion tracking.
4. Activity within the LMS e.g. forums, quizzes etc. might be tracked using Tin Can to an LRS.

It sounds like from your question that number three is what you're looking for? The high level approach here would be to have these external sources feed into an LRS and then push/pull that data from the LRS into the LMS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew, I agree, number 3 is what I am trying to achieve. I would really appreciate it if you could please elaborate on how you push/pull the data from the LRS into an LMS. I already have a whole bunch of statements working, I just don't understand this last step in completion tracking in the LMS. Thanks!

Comment: The relevant part of the spec is here: https://github.com/adlnet/xAPI-Spec/blob/master/xAPI.md#stmtapiget What programming language are you using? Perhaps I can find you an example. You should use one of the libraries at http://tincanapi.com/libraries

Comment: Here's an example of what the Moodle plugin does: https://github.com/garemoko/moodle-mod_tincanlaunch/blob/master/lib.php#L458

Comment: We use an efront LMS http://www.efrontlearning.net/ ... And we use javascript. That moodle link is interesting. Thanks for all the help, I need some time to really look into all the links you've sent me!

Comment: I know efront does have some native Tin Can support. Have you contacted them to see what's possible out of the box?

Comment: Andrew, your link to the specification points to the table of contents (the specification seems to have been split into three separate parts) - could you please specify the relevant part of the spec or provide a new link? Also, would it be possible for you to provide an example of an LMS pulling a request from an LRS using PHP? Many thanks.

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/adlnet/xAPI-Spec/blob/master/xAPI-Communication.md#213-get-statements

Comment: PHP Get statements example: https://github.com/garemoko/moodle-mod_tincanlaunch/blob/master/lib.php#L654-L693

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [cmi5](https://github.com/AICC/CMI-5_Spec_Current), a protocol for xAPI that defines communication between the LMS, LRS and learning content.  The determination that a content module has been completed and/or passed is defined in this specification.

Comment: This would be better off as a comment, as it does not necessarily answer the question, just points to sources where answers may be.

Comment: Yes, by all means let's make sure to answer people's questions literally and absolutely not address the larger questions they are struggling with.  The narrower the scope and limited the answers the happier everyone will be.  Sheesh